# iPhone TBXML - Loop through reponses

Tags: iphone, xml, sdk, xcode

What's the best way to loop through this to get all the XML items out and assign them to the Cell.text as an array?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil) {
        Cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    TBXML * XML = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tomstest.info/ios/results.xml"]] retain];

    TBXMLElement *rootXML = XML.rootXMLElement;
    TBXMLElement *results = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"location" parentElement:rootXML];  
    TBXMLElement *WOEID = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"CompanyName" parentElement:results]; 
    NSString *woeid = [TBXML textForElement:WOEID];


    Cell.text = woeid;
    return Cell;

}
```

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you really shouldn't download the content of your file in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The method is called once for each cell: you would end up downloading the xml file many times.

`TBXML` does not support XPath queries, so you'll have to loop through the results.
Something like

```
NSMutableArray *cellTitlesBuffer = [NSMutableArray array];
TBXMLElement *locationNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"location" parentElement:rootXML]; 
if (locationNode) {
    NSString *cellTitle = nil;
    do {
        TBXMLElement *woeidNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"CompanyName" parentElement:locationNode];
        [cellTitlesBuffer addObject:[TBXML textForElement:woeidNode]];
    } while (locationNode = locationNode->nextSibling);
}
```

Then store the titles buffer in a class variable (say cellTitles) and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
Cell.textLabel.text = [cellTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```